# How to define column type of data that is being written to a AWS Redshift Postgres DB in python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, amazon-redshift

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
A       B                       C         D
80.00   2020-03-07 19:36:50     testing   approved
80.00   2020-03-07 19:46:50     testing   approved
```

I have successfully written this pandas dataframe to the database like so:

```
conn = create_engine('postgresql://username:password@redshift-blablabla.eu-west-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/database_name')

dataframe.to_sql('table_name', conn,index=False, if_exists='replace')
```

When I try to use this table as a source to visualize data in Superset I noticed that everything is stored as varchar and I cant use column `B` as a datestamp to serialize the data.

How can I define column type when writing to a database? And should the datestamp only have date and no hours to be valid as a datestamp?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**to_sql** has a parameter **dtype** by which you can provide the data types for individual columns as a dictionary or for all columns at once as a scalar. Have you tried it?

> dtype : dict or scalar, optional
>
> Specifying the datatype for columns. If a dictionary is used, the keys should be the column names and the values should be the SQLAlchemy types or strings for the sqlite3 legacy mode. If a scalar is provided, it will be applied to all columns.